# How can i send text from element with id to function on click?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, copy

I want that when i press the button it will copy the "hello"
but i get this error:
copyText.select is not a function

how to fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="aaa">hello</span>
    <button onclick="copy('#aaa')">copy</button>
    <script>
        function copy(text)
        {
            var copyText = text;
            copyText.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            console.log(document.getElementById('text'));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select text of a span using select function. You have to create a temporary input with the value of the text of the span. select the value in the input using select() and copy the text and then delete the input

```js
        function copy(text)
        {
            var copyText = document.getElementById(text).textContent;
            document.querySelector('#aux').innerHTML+=('<input id="a" value='+copyText+'>')
            document.getElementById("a").select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.querySelector('#aux').innerHTML="";
            //console.log(document.getElementById('text'));
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="aaa">hello</span>
    <button onclick="copy('aaa')">copy</button>
   <span id="aux"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the former one without parenthesis, because it is a variable.